# how to preserve links when scraping a table with beautiful soup and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Scraping a web to get a table, using `Beautiful soup` and `Pandas`. One of the columns got some urls. When I pass html to pandas, `href` are lost.

is there any way of preserving the url link just for that column?

Example data (edited for better suit ral case):

```
  <html>
        <body>
          <table>
              <tr>
               <td>customer</td>
               <td>country</td>
               <td>area</td>
               <td>website link</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>IBM</td>
               <td>USA</td>
               <td>EMEA</td>
               <td><a href="http://www.ibm.com">IBM site</a></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CISCO</td>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>EMEA</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.cisco.com">cisco site</a></td>
         </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>unknown company</td>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>EMEA</td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </body>
  </html>
```

My python code:

```
    file = open(url,"r")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')

    parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[1] 

    df = pd.read_html(str(parsed_table),encoding='utf-8')[0]

 df
```

Output (exported to CSV):

```
customer;country;area;website
IBM;USA;EMEA;IBM site
CISCO;USA;EMEA;cisco site
unknown company;USA;EMEA;
```

df output is ok but the link is lost. I need to preserve the link. The URL at least.

any hint?

Comment: Enhancement for Pandas related to your question is located here: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14608

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13141

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check if tag exists this way:

```
 import numpy as np

 with open(url,"r") as f:
     sp = bs.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
     tb = sp.find_all('table')[56] 
     df = pd.read_html(str(tb),encoding='utf-8', header=0)[0]
     df['href'] = [np.where(tag.has_attr('href'),tag.get('href'),"no link") for tag in tb.find_all('a')]
```

Answer (score 16):

`pd.read_html` assumes the data you are interested in is in the text, not the tag attributes. However, it isn't hard to scrape the table yourself:

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd

with open(url,"r") as f:
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
    parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[1] 
    data = [[td.a['href'] if td.find('a') else 
             ''.join(td.stripped_strings)
             for td in row.find_all('td')]
            for row in parsed_table.find_all('tr')]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
    print(df)
```

yields

```
          customer country  area          website link
0              IBM     USA  EMEA    http://www.ibm.com
1            CISCO     USA  EMEA  http://www.cisco.com
2  unknown company     USA  EMEA
```

Comment: KeyError: 'href'    , seems that not all rows has links  unutbu

Comment: ""tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
and throws an exception if it's not there."""

Comment: Does not work if merged cells are used like col span or row span > 1

Comment: Great answer, but code extremely complicated, use solution by PythonMan below

Comment: In case the columns are in th-tags change: columns = [''.join(th.stripped_strings) for th in parsed_table.find_all('th')]

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do it if you have more than one link to grab from html table. Instead of making list comprehension I would rather go with separeated for loops so code is more readable to those who are new to python and it is easier to adjust code ore handle errors if they emerge. I hope it will help someone.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = table.find('table')
thead = table.find('thead')
column_names = [th.text.strip() for th in thead.find_all('th')]

data = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = []
    for td in row.find_all('td'):
        td_check = td.find('a')
        if td_check is not None:
            link = td.a['href']
            row_data.append(link)
        else:
            not_link = ''.join(td.stripped_strings)
            if not_link == '':
                 not_link = None
            row_data.append(not_link)
    data.append(row_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=column_names)
df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

for row in df_dict:
    print(row)
```

Comment: In case If there are multiplr tables Use     :                                             
    table = soup.find_all('table')[1]   where [1] is index of table you are intrested in.