# How to extract image src from the website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I tried scraping the table rows from the [website](https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en) to get the data on corona virus spread.

I wanted to extract the src for all the  tags so as to get the source of the flag's image along with all the data for each country. Could someone help ?

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en")
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1]

df.to_csv("Data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What part of this is trying to  scrape image sources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to preserve links when scraping a table with beautiful soup and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285417/how-to-preserve-links-when-scraping-a-table-with-beautiful-soup-and-pandas)

Comment: @ScottHunter If you look at the table in the link the first columns td has two tags in it, a span tag and an img tag. read_html will not collect the img tag or its reference it will only write the contents of the span tag in the dataframe. The OP is asking how can they get the link ref to the flag from the image tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Gareth's answer has already been accepted, his answer inspired me to write this one form a pandas point of view. Since we know the url for flags are a fixed pattern and the only thing that changes is the name. We can create a new column by lowercasing the name, replacing spaces with underscores and then weaving the name in the fixed URL pattern

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en")
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1]
df['flag_url'] = df.apply(lambda row: f"https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/{row.Location.lower().replace(' ', '_')}_icon_square.svg", axis=1)
df.to_csv("Data.csv", index=False)
driver.quit()
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE**

```
Location,Confirmed,Cases per 1M people,Recovered,Deaths,flag_url
Worldwide,882068,125.18,185067,44136,https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/worldwide_icon_square.svg
United Kingdom,29474,454.19,135,2352,https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/united_kingdom_icon_square.svg
United States,189441,579.18,7082,4074,https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/united_states_icon_square.svg
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the most genious way, but since you have the page source already, how about using regex to match the urls of the images?

```
import re
print (re.findall(r'https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/.+?.svg', driver.page_source))
```

The image links are in order so it matches the order of confirmed cases - except that on my computer, the country I'm in right now is at the top of the list.

If this is not what you want, I can delete this answer.

As mentioned by [@Chris Doyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212401/chris-doyle) in the comments, this can even simply done by noticing the urls are the same, with ".+?" replaced by the country's name (all lowercase, connected with underscores). You have that information in the `csv` file.

```
country_name = "United Kingdom"
url = "https://www.gstatic.com/onebox/sports/logos/flags/"
url += '_'.join(country_name.lower().split())
url += '.svg'
print (url)
```

Also be sure to check out his answer using purely panda :)

Comment: What exactly is stuff variable for could  you explain?

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad, it's just `driver.page_source`. Edited

Comment: nice suggestion, this could even more smply be acheived by the fact that the urls are all the same other than the country  name and the OP already has that so can just make a column in the df using that info

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was just the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome Gareth. A well deserved accepted answer, I have added a pandas based answer for completeness but that was totally inspired by this answers initial idea that you can use a regex to get the url data

Comment: rip guess i need to answer a few more questions to get 500rep :P good job

Comment: Crap well now i feel bad since the OP had accepted your answer......i was only adding mines for completeness to the question, i didnt expect them to change the accepted answer. For that i am sorry

Comment: oh nonono i just answer a few more bad questions and farm haha ok i shouldn't say that now i'm gonna get banned or sth

Comment: Hehe, if i could donate some rep i would. As i would never have come up with my answer had it not been for your regex idea