# Impossible to get specific table with `read_html

Tags: python, html, database, pandas

I am trying to access a table with `read_html` function ([URL](https://geco.amf-france.org/Bio/res_part.aspx?NomProd=&OrderBy=&OrderBySens=&NumAgr=&CodeISIN=&NomSoc=&selectNRJ=OPCVM&ClassProd=0&TypeProd=&npos=0)).

My problem is that it seems that `read_html` does not find my table whereas it exists.
I don't know why except that the table I want to read has the same attribute than an other one.

I did first :

```
url = 'https://geco.amf-france.org/Bio/res_part.aspx?NomProd=&OrderBy=&OrderBySens=&NumAgr=&CodeISIN=&NomSoc=&selectNRJ=OPCVM&ClassProd=0&TypeProd=&npos='
df = pd.read_html(url)
df
```

it returns 3 df store in df[0], df[1](https://geco.amf-france.org/Bio/res_part.aspx?NomProd=&OrderBy=&OrderBySens=&NumAgr=&CodeISIN=&NomSoc=&selectNRJ=OPCVM&ClassProd=0&TypeProd=&npos=0) and df[3] but none is the main table that I saw. It is just little table ie and not the 'big' one as in the image :

```
[                                                   0
 0  Recherche Liste  Vendredi 2 octobre 2020  Prod...,
                    0             1                     2  \
 0          Recherche     Recherche             Recherche   
 1  Produit financier  Gestionnaire  Valeurs liquidatives   
 
                                3        4                       5  \
 0                      Recherche    Liste                   Liste   
 1  Associations Professionnelles  Encours  Gestionnaires agrÃ©Ã©s   
 
                                        6                        7  
 0                                  Liste  Vendredi 2 octobre 2020  
 1  Gestionnaires de l'EEE - Passeport IN   Recherche Documentaire  ,
                    0   1                         2      3
 0   Code ISIN part : NaN          Nom de Produit :    NaN
 1  NÂ° d'agrÃ©ment : NaN  Classification produit :    NaN
 2           Nom SG : NaN       RÃ©gime juridique :  OPCVM]
```

I also tried :

```
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class' : 'ctcoltableresult2'})
df
```

but it returns nothing

### [image: The main table I would like to get]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if you specify the falvor as bs4 it works.  I also added attrs to only get the 'big' table.

```
url = 'https://geco.amf-france.org/Bio/res_part.aspx?NomProd=&OrderBy=&OrderBySens=&NumAgr=&CodeISIN=&NomSoc=&selectNRJ=OPCVM&ClassProd=0&TypeProd=&npos='
df = pd.read_html(url, flavor='bs4', attrs={'class':'ctcoltableresult2'})
df
```

Comment: it works effectively but why just add flavor='bs4' change the result ?

How to get also the link in columns ?

Comment: bs4 is the beautifulsoup parsing engine which is a little slower but better at parsing in some (most) situations.  As for keeping the links you can't do it with read_html.  read_html assumes you are looking for the text.  You will have to parse the HTML yourself.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285417/how-to-preserve-links-when-scraping-a-table-with-beautiful-soup-and-pandas